# easygui multchoicebox not allowing me to select multiple items

Tags: python-2.7, easygui

I can create an easygui multchoicebox that displays multiple items but I am unable to select more than one item at a time. ( multchoicebox is acting like choicebox).
here is some example code:

```
import easygui as g
g.multchoicebox(msg = "Hi", title = "Hello", choices = ['bill','bob','big','brat','braut'])
```

I can only choose one of these 5 items.

I am using easygui.97.4

anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Appears to be a be in EasyGUI. See https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/78 for bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted easygui version 97.4 then put version 96 in my python "site-packages" Now multchoicebox let's me select multiple items.

Apparently there is something wrong with easygui 97.4